# Prove that $\lim_{n \to\infty}{a_n}=L$, then $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\lim_{n \to\infty}{a_n}=L$, then $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence

First I suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and I want to demostrate that it converges in a real number $L$

Comment: What you write starting from "First I suppose" looks rather like a proof attempt in the opposite direction: If $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy, then it converges to some real  number $L$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Write out the definition of $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = L$, and then use the triangle inequality

$$|a_n - a_m| \leq |a_n - L| + |a_m - L|$$